# Cannot Display More than one images in the canvas of tkinter

Tags: tkinter, python-imaging-library, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to create the images rendering in the series one by one.But generally it shows last image and other images are invisible.I found that there is a problem with reference variable(cj.img = t) which remains same at every time.What should I have to do???

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import PIL
from PIL import Image,ImageTk

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")

cj = Canvas(root,width = 600,height = 300,relief = SUNKEN,bd = 1,bg = "#494949")
cj.grid(row = 1,column = 0,sticky = "news")

w = 0
imh = ["myphoto.png","new2.png","format.png"]
def showimg():
     for i in range(len(imh)) :
          t = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = imh[i])
          cj.img = t
          cj.create_image(100,(i * 50),image = t,anchor = N)

showimg()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there. Each image must be defined separately, otherwise picture `t` overwrites the previous one. So below code should give a hint.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, SUNKEN
import PIL
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


root = Tk()
root.geometry('600x400')

cj = Canvas(root, width=600, height=300, relief=SUNKEN, bd=1, bg="#494949")
cj.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nesw')

image_files = ['myphoto.png', 'new2.png', 'format.png']
pics = []


def show_img():
    for i, image_file in enumerate(image_files):

          pics.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=image_file))
          cj.create_image(100, i * 50, image=pics[i], anchor='n')

show_img()
root.mainloop()
```

Tips:

- Do not import *
- Use enumerate() in the for loop to get index i and the file_name
- Use more descriptive file names
- As per PEP8 add a space after a comma

Some useful documentation: [The Tkinter Canvas Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_image-method)

Comment: Thank You Sir, It worked for me.I will try to make my program more descriptive as you recommended.

Comment: Thanks, just tick answered to give me some kudos thanks.